# adding required country basemap behind a plot, not very detailed , only outer boundaries

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I want to include india and neighbouring countries political boundaries in the plot achieved

How to do this?

My result is this:

[image]

What I want is like this:

[image]

Code:-

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import shapefile as shp
import seaborn as sns


file = "anth_oc.csv"
lat = np.linspace(3.1,35.7,75)
lon = np.linspace(63.3,95.3,75)
df = pd.read_csv(file)
#data = df[:,1:]
data = df.values


X,Y = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)



sns.set(context="notebook", style="darkgrid",
        rc={"axes.axisbelow": False})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,8),dpi = 300)


contour = plt.contour(X, Y, data,colors="white")

plt.clabel(contour, colors = 'black', fmt = '%2.f', fontsize=8)
plt.grid(True)
#plt.grid(True)

co_plot = ax.contourf(X,Y,data,cmap = "Reds",levels=np.linspace(0,20,11))
#ax.clabel(co_plot, inline=True)
plt.xlabel("Longitude(\N{DEGREE SIGN}E)")
plt.ylabel("Latitude(\N{DEGREE SIGN}N)")
#plt.title("Contour plot of CO levels")



cbar = plt.colorbar(co_plot,extend='both',orientation = 'horizontal',pad = 0.1,aspect = 50)
cbar.set_label('Annual OC Concentration(ton/m2) [2018] ')
#plot_shape(com_id,comuna,ax)
fig.savefig("anth_oc.png")
```

Comment: something like: https://melaniesoek0120.medium.com/data-visualization-how-to-plot-a-map-with-geopandas-in-python-73b10dcd4b4b ?

Comment: No, its not the same, I have checked the link already, its not working for me. they have a different kind of a dataset altogether, I have a meshgrid in the excel format with values at every lat lon

Comment: What projection do you want to plot your data on?